# What will happen to my app on Appstore after Flurry's sunset?

Tags: analytics, mobile-application, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have a lot of apps with iOS and Android which are live and using Flurry Analytics.

As per [Flurry](https://www.flurry.com) they will sunset on March 15, 2024.

A lot of calls are already there for logging the events and crashes. Do I need to update all my apps by removing flurry or do can I leave it as is? What are the consequences of all the flurry related calls?

Answer (score 0):

As Flurry  decommission all the services after 3/15/24, the incoming traffic form the SDKs won't be processed.
The Flurry's (DNS) servers will return 200 status to all incoming traffic, which in turn will allow the apps and Flurry SDK to function properly.

In other words, the apps with the Flurry SDKs, should remain fully functional for the foreseeable future. All the traffic is one way, from the SDKs to the servers, Flurry SDK does not receive anything from the servers.
There is no (immediate) need to update your apps to remove the Flurry SDK.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere by flurry?

Comment: Hey any one have any official document mentioning same?

Comment: The most relevant document I have found is the [Flurry Sunsetting](https://www.flurry.com/blog/flurry-sunsetting/) page on Flurry's Blog but there is no mention of how the Flurry API will function after 15-Mar-2024.
I intend to push an app update to remove the Flurry Analytics package from my apps just in case this 200 behaviour doesn't happen.